# A generic error occurred in GDI+ saving

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file, impersonation

I'm trying to save file from one server to another. Users would be upload a jpeg file to server. In my controller I'm getting file data with "HttpPostedFileBase". If I want to upload this file on local server, it has no problem (Web-based Admin application IP is xxx.xxx.xxx). But if I want to upload data to another server (IP is yyy.yyy.yyy) I'm getting this error that I shown on title.

I also doing impersonation to reach interested folder. The folder has IIS_USER,NetworkService,Everyone users full admin rights on (yyy.yyy.yyy) machine.

Also I have tried to do this code with File Copy, move in exe file and I havent got any error. So this code giving error just in ASP.Net MVC Application.

You can check partial code below :

```
if (isImpersonated)
        {

            //File.ResizeImage(1000, 1000).Save(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PicturePath"], fileName)));
            //File.ResizeImage(500, 500).Save(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MarinaPicturePath"], string.Format("{0}-medium{1}", imgName, Path.GetExtension(File.FileName)))));
            //File.ResizeImage(250, 250).Save(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MarinaPicturePath"], string.Format("{0}-small{1}", imgName, Path.GetExtension(File.FileName)))));

            //File.Copy("C:\\test\\asd.txt", "\\\\31.123.1.123\\C$\\test\\asd123.txt");
            //System.IO.File.Copy("C:\\test\\asd.txt", "\\\\31.123.1.123\\C$\\test\\asd123.txt");   


            //File.ResizeImage(1600, 1200).Save(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PicturePath"], fileName)));

            File.ResizeImage(1000, 1000).Save(Path.Combine("\\\\31.123.1.123\\C$\\test\\", fileName));
            File.ResizeImage(500, 500).Save(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("\\\\31.123.1.123\\C$\\test\\", string.Format("{0}-medium{1}", imgName, Path.GetExtension(File.FileName)))));
            File.ResizeImage(250, 250).Save(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("\\\\31.123.1.123\\C$\\test\\", string.Format("{0}-small{1}", imgName, Path.GetExtension(File.FileName)))));

            GC.Collect();
            //var asd = StreamToByteArray(File.InputStream);
            //System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine("\\\\31.123.1.123\\C$\\test\\", fileName), asd);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer! If somebody would get this error, should be check Impersination class and just set `const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 9`